# Font to pair with latin modern

Tags: fonts, sectioning, typography, latin-modern

I am looking for a typeface to use in headings and to pair with Latin Modern, which is irreplaceable for the body of the text.
I would particularly appreciate suggestions of sans serif families, but every suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Either choose Latin Modern Sans or a font that has as little in common with Latin Modern Roman as possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Latin Modern is a complete family of fonts, including serif, sans, typewriter and some other families.

The following is actually a relatively small sample of what is available from Latin Modern:

[image: LM sampler]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cfr-lm,microtype}

\begin{document}
\newcommand\dog{The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.}

\dog

\textbf{\dog}

\textsc{\dog}

\textsi{\dog}

\textit{\dog}

\textui{\dog}

{\normalfont\fontfamily{clmqs}\selectfont
  \dog

  \bfseries\dog}

{\sffamily\dog

  \bfseries\dog

  \fontseries{sbc}\selectfont\dog}

{\ttfamily\dog

  \bfseries\dog

  \lgweight\dog}

{\tmstyle\dog

  \bfseries\dog

  \lgweight\dog

  \cdwidth\dog}

{\tistyle\dog

  \itshape\dog}

\end{document}
```

Comment: yes, I knew, but those do not excite me. There is not any other font that would match LModern, just as heading?

Comment: @cal7F Could you edit your question to clarify what you're looking for? You're asking for a sans serif font that goes well with latin modern (serif, I presume), and the font that does that the best is obviously the sans-serif version of latin modern. But you say here you don't want it because it doesn't "excite" you. So you're looking for a "cool" non-lmodern sans-serif font that goes well with lmodern serif?

Comment: Right and to me it does not seems so crazy as you make it sound. Anyway, seen the wonder caused by this request, do I have to suppose it is a bad idea to use another font, even in the headings?

Comment: @cal7F As egreg says, if you don't want the best match, choose something as different as possible. But remember that you don't want people to notice the typography unless you are writing something very specific. Good typography is a vehicle for the content and does not distract from that content. At least, for standard documents of the kind most often produced with TeX.

Comment: @cal7F Take a look at http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/sansseriffonts.html. Just don't pick something which will look like a not-quite-right match. Either use a match (Latin Modern Sans) or use something different enough to be an obvious choice-of-something-different.

Answer (score 0):

When you don't like the look of cm sans/lm sans, you can try the ecbright fonts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{cmbright}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
Zwei Boxkämpfer jagten Quirin über den großen Sylter Deich.

\$ \pounds \texteuro
\end{document}
```

[image: ecbright font sample]